# Check if all values are defined and not empty strings

Tags: javascript, nan, arrow-functions

I'm trying to simplify the following validation so I can have a simple and short arrow function:

```
var isARealNumber = (val) => val !== "" && val !== undefined;
```

`"" >= 0` will cast `""` to `0` so it doesn't work, but I'm looking for something similar short.

```js
var values1 = ["", "1", "2"];
var values2 = [undefined, "1", "2"];
var values3 = ["0", "1", "2"];

var isARealNumber= (val) => val !== "" && val !== undefined;

console.log(values1.every(isARealNumber));
console.log(values2.every(isARealNumber));
console.log(values3.every(isARealNumber));
```

Comment: To answer this, we'd need a much more thorough definition of what `isARealNumber` is supposed to accept. Just whole numbers, or fractional as well? Just decimal, or other formats like hex and octal? How about scientific notation (for instance, `"1e6"` which is 1,000,000)? Thousands separators? What *kinds* of thousands separators (I know of at least three in common use worldwide). Negative numbers? A leading unary `+`?

Comment: Oh sure, it's not that complex at all, there will only be real numbers from 0 to a couple millions (Integers). So I just need to filter out the undefined and empty values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) here with [`RegExp#test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method.

```js
var values1 = ["", "1", "2"];
var values2 = [undefined, "1", "2"];
var values3 = ["0", "1", "2"];
var reg = /^\d+$/

var isARealNumber= (val) => reg.test(val);

console.log(values1.every(isARealNumber));
console.log(values2.every(isARealNumber));
console.log(values3.every(isARealNumber));
```

Comment: I like the approach! but unfortunately it doesn't really help the readability :/

Comment: `/^\d+$/` for digit match or more readability use character class `/^[0-9]+$/`